# How to extract nested img tag information with Jsoup on Android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to get image name and its image URL. My html is like this:

```
<td class="text-center">  
    <a href="MYLINK.html">
      <img src="IMAGE INK.jpg" alt="IMAGE NAME" title="MY TITILE" class="img-thumbnail" />
    </a>
</td>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the image element, e.g.:

```
Element image = document.select("img").first();
String url = image.attr("abs:src");
String name = image.attr("abs:title");
```

or try playing also with and see what info you want:

```
.attr("src")
.attr("title")
```

Comment: Is there a way to display a thumbnail from a website without downloading the entire source using JSoup?

Answer (score 1):

```
String your_html = "<td class=\"text-center\"><a href=\"MYLINK.html\"><img src=\"IMAGE INK.jpg\" alt=\"IMAGE NAME\" title=\"MY TITILE\" class=\"img-thumbnail\" /></a></td>";
Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Element element = document.body();
Element link = element.select("img.img-thumbnail").first(); // Img with class img-thumbnail
System.out.println(link.attr("src")); //The attribute, 'src' , within the selected img tag
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

i done it by

```
 Element e4 = row.select("td.text-center > a > img").first();
                    String URL = e4.attr("src");
                    String TITLE = e4.attr("title");
                    System.out.println("URL  = " + URL);
                    System.out.println("TITLE  = " + TITLE);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check that e4 is not null (ie `e4! = null`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I did it.

```
String html_to_parse = "<td class=\"text-center\"><a href=\"MYLINK.html\"><img src=\"IMAGE INK.jpg\" alt=\"IMAGE NAME\" title=\"MY TITILE\" class=\"img-thumbnail\" /></a></td>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html_to_parse);
String imageUrl = doc.select("img").attr("src");
String imageName = doc.select("img").attr("title");
```